# Add new NIC to existing Subnet

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have an existing vNet and subnet and I'm trying to deploy a new NIC to the Subnet with the following bicep

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param nicName string
param vNetName string
param subnetName string

resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-02-01' existing = {
  name: vNetName
  scope: resourceGroup('myRgName')
}

resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-02-01' existing = {
  parent: vnet
  name: subnetName
}

resource nsg 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2021-08-01' = {
  name: '${nicName}-nsg'
  location: location
}

resource nic 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2021-08-01' = {
  name: nicName
  location: location
  dependsOn: [
    subnet
  ]
  properties: {
    ipConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'ipConfig'
        properties: {
          privateIPAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'    
          subnet: subnet
          primary: true
          privateIPAddressVersion: 'IPv4'
        }
      }
    ]
    networkSecurityGroup: nsg
  }
}
```

I compile the template and try to deploy but I'm getting the error `Value for reference id is missing. Path properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.subnet.` which appears to be caused by the ARM not finding the subnet (which exists and I have access to).

The json portion of it looks like this

```
"subnet": "[reference(extensionResourceId(format('/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}', subscription().subscriptionId, 'myRgName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', split(parameters('subnetName'), '/')[0], split(parameters('subnetName'), '/')[1]), '2021-02-01', 'full')]",
```

Comment: I think you should just specify the id of the nsg: `networkSecurityGroup: { id: nsg.id }` something like that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
subnet: {
  id: subnet.id
}
```

for the subnet reference in the NIC's properties... you'll need the same for the `networkSecurityGroup` as Thomas mentioned.